# Guidance how implement custom art Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I need some guidance in how insert custom art in my app.

For example I want to implement a custom layer on top of the progress bar, so I just have to create the art and implement on top of the progress bar or should I do something else?

As I am begining I am facing this sort of doubts.

To clarify, I want to know how the implementation of the custom arts work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, you want to implement a standard `UIProgressView` but overlay artwork on top of it?  Or you want to implement a custom subclass of `UIProgressView`?  Can you described the outcome that you're seeking?

Comment: What is the better way? I want to do some kind of thermometer.

Comment: It's definitely possible to alter the appearance in any way you like.  See the answer from @Brendt below and a tutorial [here](http://goto11.net/skinning-a-uiprogressview-with-drawrect-and-images/)

Answer (score 0):

This information in pertinent to iOS development (not sure if it applies to OSX)

If you check out the docs [UIProgressView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can see that you are able to update both the track and progress image. Which means you are able to alter the appearance of the progress bar completely.

e.g.

```
[progressView setProgressImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress_image.png"]];
[progressView setTrack:[UIImage imageNamed:@"track_image.png"]];
```

If you want to add additional images or labels (say a marker and percentage label) to the progressView then as UIProgressView is a subclass of UIView you can just add the images to the view (but first adjust the new image\labels frame so it is positioned correctly).

e.g.

```
UIImageView* marker = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_line.png"]];
[marker setFrame:CGRectMake(10.5, marker.frame.origin.y + 13, marker.frame.size.width,  marker.frame.size.height)];
[progressView addSubview:marker];
```

Comment: I reckon the difference in adding additional images and add a image in setTrackImage is I can manipulate the images/labels as I want whereas the other option is static. Am I right? I've tried your code but no additional image is appearing

Comment: And if I use the first snippet the progressImage(the system default) is multiple all over the trackImage